how to include a partial filename as variable for a Pandoc template?
I try to include a partial named in the YAML header (in the variable frontmatterFile), i.e. a variable inside the call for the partial:
The code is:
$if(frontmatterFile)$ 
    ${ ${frontmatterFile}.dtpl() }
$else$
    ${  frontmatter_short.dtpl() }
$endif$

Latex produces just the value in the frontmatterFile but does not process the partial - confirmed in checking the produced tex file.
Is there a way to have the variable expanded to the filename and then used as partial?

Pandoc's template engine doesn't support this. You could, however, write a custom Lua writer that replaces that set's that value in the template.
local outformat = 'latex'  -- set output format

Template = -- define template, or load from external file

function Writer (doc, opts)
  -- get frontmatter file from metadata or variables
  local frontmatter_file = pandoc.utils.stringify(doc.meta.frontmatter_file)
    or opts.variables.frontmatter_file
  opts.template = modify_template(opts.template, frontmatter_file)
  return pandoc.write(doc, outformat, opts)
end


Thank you for the suggestion. I did not think  about this but see how I could add this to my processor. I assume it could be written in Haskell in stead of Lua?

Definitely, Haskell is a great choice if you plan to maintain your code long-term! If you'd like to share it easily, then Lua is nice because pandoc has an interpreter built in.

I use Haskell to convert a blog to html and pdf, quite a bit of code. But I see your point about sharing!
